# How to get Graphics Card Max Power in NVIDIA Control Panel by NvAPI?

Tags: nvidia, nvapi

I want to get my graphics card's max power through NvAPI. The graphics card's max power can be seen in Nvidia Control Panel on my laptop with an RTX30s card; click [help] - [System Information].

How can I obtain the same information through NvAPI?

Comment: the Graphics Card Max Power only can be seen in Laptop with RTX30s card

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.